# Server Error After OpenEdx installation

Tags: ubuntu-server, openedx

I just installed OpenEDX script on a Ubuntu Server following [this tutorial](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/OpenOPS/Native+Open+edX+Ubuntu+12.04+64+bit+Installation),I get no error while installation but after it finished and when I tried to visit it I'm getting Server Error

Comment: I suggest you set DEBUG=True in your settings to check the error stacktrace. You may also check the server logs to find the exact error.

Comment: can you give me more details please

Answer (score 3):

Please check the services status:

```
/edx/bin/supervisorctl status
```

And have look on log files:

```
/edx/var/log/
```